# Decision Tree Bayes rules / Maximax / Maximin

Tags: data-mining, statistics, visualization, decision-trees

I need to draw a decision tree about this subject :

> The research and development manager in an old oil company, which is
>   considering making some changes, lists the following courses of action
>   for the company:
>
> (i) Adopt a process developed by another oil company. This would cost
>   €7 million in royalties and yield a net €20 million profit (before
>   paying the royalty).
>
> (ii) Carry out one or two (not simultaneously) alternative research
>   projects :
>
> (R1) the more expensive one has a 0.8 chance of success; net profit
>   €16 million and a further €6 million in royalties. If it fails there
>   will be a net loss of €10 million.
>
> (R2) the alternative research programme is less expensive but only has
>   a 0.7 chance of success with a net profit of €15 million and a further
>   €5 million in royalties. If it fails a net loss of €6 million will be
>   incurred.
>
> (iii) Make no changes. After meeting current operating costs the
>   company expects to make a net €15 million profit from its existing
>   process. Failure of one research program would still leave open all
>   remaining courses of action (including the other research programme).

I need also to indicate the different payoffs. This is what I've done so far :
[image]

I would like to be sure that I'm going in the right direction since I'm a beginner with decision trees. And then I need to decide the best course of action using Bayes, Maximax and Maximin rules.